# Change image placed into another image while hovering over text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying change the image placed inside the phone mock up frame. The problem is that images don't change in that specific location even tough I have the code for it. Can anyone help out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Mobile plugin</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->

  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">     </script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">   </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="nexus">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-5 col-md-4">
          <img src="images/nexus.png">
          <div class="image">
            <div id="im">
              <img src="images/2a.png" id="image2">
              <img src="images/3.png" id="image3">
              <img src="images/4.png" id="image4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="logofix">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" width="160px">
            <ul class="image-switch">
              <li data-feature="feature-1">
                <h4>Connect</h4>
                <p>Connect the plugin using various methods.</p>
              </li>
              <li data-feature="feature-2">
                <h4>Time spend connected</h4>
                <p>This will allow you to monitor how long</p>
                <p>have been connected each day and</p>
                <p>how much data have you transferred.</p>
              </li>
              <li data-feature="feature-3">
                <h4>Browsing Habits</h4>
                <p>Shows you what percentage of your time</p>
                <p> is spent on different tasks and the amount </p>
                <p> of daily visits.</p>
              </li>
              <li data-feature="feature-4">
                <h4>Dashboard</h4>
                <p>The dashboard gives a nice and simple</p>
                <p> preview of the product functionalities,</p>
                <p> allowing you to navigate easily.</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3 /jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS file which sets the location of both the phone frame and the actual images :

```
.logofix {
   right: 60 % ;
   position: static;
   top: 30 % ;
   display: block;
 }

 #
 wrapper {
   position: relative;
   margin - right: auto;
   margin - left: auto;
   padding - top: 72 px;

 }#
 wrapper, .wrapper {
   min - height: 100 % ;
   height: auto!important;
   box - sizing: border - box;
 }

 li: hover {
   padding - left: 10 px;
   transition: all 0.2 s ease - out 0 s;
 }

 /* Settings and properties of the list text block*/
 li {
   list - style - type: none;
   font - family: Open Sans;
   font - size: 16 px;
   margin: 0 px;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   width: 100 % ;
   padding: 5 px 0 px;
   position: relative;
   transition: all 0.2 s ease - out 0 s;
 }
 /*END of Settings and properties of the list text block*/

 #
 image2 {

   height: 390 px;
   width: 212 px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 42 px;
   left: 23 px;
   z - index: 1;
 }
```

I am using this simple short javascript to change the images on hover but I'm not sure if the problem is not from it as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.image-switch li').mouseover(function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'a') return;
    var image_src = $('a', this).data('image');
    var img = $('.image-container img');

    if(img.attr('src') != image_src) { // only do the fade if other image is selected
      img.fadeOut('slow', function() { // fadeout the current image
      img.attr('src', image_src).fadeIn(); // load and fadein new image
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This image show how the website looks and where should the images change when someone hovers with their mouse on the text on the right
[image]

Comment: I wonder how to do trigger hover or mouseover event on a mobile device .

Comment: It's not a mobile device, the idea is when you hover over the text on the right, the image INSIDE the mobile phone to change...

Comment: @DinoMyte He never said it was on mobil device if you look at the screen you'll see a mobil but not direct correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Js in this specific case why not just doing something like :

```
.thingToHover ~ .imageToShow
{
  display : block;
}
```

Of course you'll need your images to be previously set as `display:none`.

If you want the **fade in / fade out** effect just add `transition : 0.5s` to the class of your images.

Here is an exemple in a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sbxkqks/2/)

Comment: That is the issue, I need to make it display in the mobile frame when it is hovering. Using display:block just makes the image appear but not in the position I need it.

Comment: You just need it to be positioned ? If it is that use `position: relative` on the frame and `position: absolute` `top: 0px` on the images.

Comment: I've added a "z index" to the other images which allows them to hide behind the first image. How can I make the hover to display them? I'm trying to to something like this   

        h4:hover + p{
  background-image:url(#image3);
  position: absolute top: 0px;
  height: 390px;
  width:212px;

  }